# Why Thread exits while using await in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I stumbled upon an issue using `await` on `async` method (could be `Task.Delay()`) in a custom thread.

The code I am trying to run looks like this:

```
// Class stuff here ...
private static async void Main(object cancellationToken) // The thread start
{
    var ct = (CancellationToken)cancellationToken;
    
    try
    {
        Init();
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Func1();
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
    catch {//some console output here}
    finally {//some console output here}

}
```

The thread exits as soon as reaches `await Task.Delay(100)` and does not execute `finally`block.

Why is that?

Removing await prevents the thread from exit, but then the program is synchronous.

Comment: Not enough information to assess the situation. What does `Init()` do? What does `Func1()` do? What is calling `Main()` from where? And why is it `async void` instead of `async Task` ? (I am in fact suspecting the culprit to be the `void`)

Comment: And why is the CancellationToken passed as `object`?

Comment: I agree Fildor, `async void` should only be used for event-handlers. A caller of such a function has no way to indicate when the task completes, because you literally don't return any task.

Comment: ^^ Which means: the process can exit before that operation finishes.

Comment: The culprit *is* `async void`. Such methods can't be awaited at all, which means whatever calls `Main` will keep on running and exit. Asynchronous Main functions have an `async Task Main` syntax, not `async void`

Comment: Th Main function is used as ThreadStart for new thread.